# QTP with open Source test management tools

Tags: qtp

My new project has QTP and no test management tool. Previously, I used QTP and QC. I am not sure that QC is in the budget for us.
What other open source test management options are there that can be integrated with QTP? By integration, I mean ones that can kick off QTP test sets and manage the results.
If possible provide sample scripts.

Looking forward for your resopnse. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other tools that support QTP/UFT integration out of the box (but there could well be). Perhaps if you mention the test management tools you are leaning towards someone maybe able suggest ways to do the integration with that tool. Failing that, QTP/UFT has a rather comprehensive API that would probably allow you to integrate it with whatever tool you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question and encompasses a lot of options to solve the problem you have mentioned.

Any open source tool?
No as per the latest list of tools there are no options of open source tools which directly interface with QTP.

What can you do?
It seems that you will have a good knowledge of programming languages. You can use OTA(Open test architecture) for solving your problem. OTA exposes the all the functionalities that QTP has. For eg: opening tests, run tests and collate the results. You might have to classify test in folder structures on drive in order to get some level of segregation.
This can be excellently integrated with VBA (Microsoft excel), C# and VB. I can put down some code samples here but that wont be helpful unless you explore OTA first. After reading a bit you can  put down specific problems here.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your post and while I know you are asking about open source tooling you may be interested in a tool has created - Enterprise Tester (http://www.enterprisetester.com). While not open source if you are a not for profit you can get a free license or if you are Education organisation you can get a license for half price. For commercial organisations a single user license starts at $10.

Enterprise Tester will allow you to integrate with QTP so you can pull automated test results in and manage both manual and automated tests in the same place. Enterprise Tester has a fully featured API (https://help.catchsoftware.com - for more information) so you can pull or push the QTP results in.

Hopefully this is helpful